# RPAD TO_CHAR gives unexpected output - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, padding, to-char

I got unexpected output using rpad, nvl and to_char combination for number datatype.

The below is my query and executed in Oracle (Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0):

SELECT RPAD(NVL(TO_CHAR(122.85,'000.000'),' '),6) FROM dual

The output:
 122.8    (note: the exact output:   122.8)

My doubt, why the last character 5) has truncated? Still the length is six including the decimal point.

Please help to understand the reason.

Regards,
Mani

Answer (score 1):

It's not truncatet, it is there.
But it is a space and you cannot see it ;)

```
SELECT RPAD(NVL(TO_CHAR(122.85,'000.000'),' '),6) x,
       length( RPAD(NVL(TO_CHAR(122.85,'000.000'),' '),6)) l,
       dump( RPAD(NVL(TO_CHAR(122.85,'000.000'),' '),6) ) dmp
FROM dual;

X               L DMP 
------ ---------- --------------------------------
 122.8          6 Typ=1 Len=6: 32,49,50,50,46,56
```

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rpad.php 


RPAD( string, padded_length [, pad_string] )


pad_string is optional, if you do not specify it, oracle assumes a space.

Answer (score 1):

TO_CHAR(122.85,'000.000') returns > 122.850<  with the blank space ahead. The blank space is reserved for the sign.
you need the `FM` modifier in the format string: `TO_CHAR(122.85,'FM000.000')`

```
SELECT RPAD(NVL(TO_CHAR(122.85,'FM000.000'),' '),6) FROM dual
```

Comment: Hi Friends,

Thank you for your comments.

Actually I wanted to know the reason, why it is adding a blank space in the first position. 
>schurik>> helped to understand the reason for thise blank space, its reserved for sign.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
SELECT NVL(TO_CHAR(122.85,'000.000'),' ') from dual;
```

return ' 122.850'

note the space before the number.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this TO_CHAR has added a space to the left of your number. I suggest you use the following:

```
SELECT RPAD(LTRIM(NVL(TO_CHAR(122.85,'000.000'),'')), 6)
FROM dual
```